# Character Selection in Corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I make an endless run game using Corona SDK and I need to make a character selection between 2 characters (boy/girl). I don't have any idea how I should start.

I tried to make 2 portraits of the character on the menu screen, but I don't know what to do on Event Touch on them. I tried to save them in a variable but I don't know how to load them in the `game.lua`. There I have:

```
local spriteSheet = sprite.newSpriteSheet("monsterSpriteSheet.png", 100, 100)
local monsterSet = sprite.newSpriteSet(spriteSheet, 1, 7)
sprite.add(monsterSet, "running", 1, 6, 600, 0)
sprite.add(monsterSet, "jumping", 7, 7, 1, 1)

    local monster = sprite.newSprite(monsterSet)
    monster:prepare("running")
    monster:play()
    monster.x = 60
    monster.y = 200
    monster.gravity = -6
    monster.accel = 0
    monster.isAlive = true
```

I've got a `main.lua` a `menu.lua` and a `game.lua`. I use `director` class for transition. Any ideas on how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass parameters through storyboard.gotoScene

```
local options = {
  effect = "crossFade",
  time = 500,
  params = { 
    character = myCharacter,
  }
}

storyboard.gotoScene( "game", options )
```

and in the game.lua

```
function scene:createScene( event )
  local params = event.params
  local character = params.character
end
```

Comment: So ,i can use bouth "storyboard" and director class?

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a data file and point to that file.

For example:

```
data.lua
local data = {}
return data
```

Then in your selection scene require data.lua and save your chosen character to it.

```
data.chosenCharacter = chosenCharater
```

Then in your game scene require data.lua again and point your character to what is saved in data.

```
local character = data.chosenCharacter
```